# Nothing display after I load the page

Tags: php, mysql

I have two dropdown. drop1_1 and tier_two. Drop_1 select all app_cn and tier_two selects app_plan_no

```
counter | app_cn   | app_plan_no 

000004  |  comp1   |  1
000172  |  comp1   |  1
000007  |  comp1   |  2
000005  |  comp2   |  1
```

When I load the page nothing displays. I need to display all records when Selected value in my drop_1 dropdown is ALL. And if I select comp1 nothing appears until I select in tier_two dropdown. I'm really having problem in my query. Anyone?

Getuser.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
$p = $_GET['p'];
$q = $_GET['q'];
$where = '';
if ( $q != 'ALL') {
    $where = " WHERE app_cn='$q' AND app_plan_no='$p'  ";
$result1 = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM app 
    $where 
    GROUP BY counter
")or die(mysqli_error());
echo'<table>'
.......
```

And here's my full code

Combobox.php

```
<script> // AJAX Implementation
function showUser() {
    str = document.getElementById("drop_1").value;
    str1 = document.getElementById("tier_two").value;
if (str == "" || str1 == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
}
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str + "&p=" + str1, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
<body onload=showUser(str="ALL")>

<?php include('func.php'); ?>
<select name="drop_1" id="drop_1" onchange="showUser()" style="overflow:scroll;width:100px;">
        <option value="ALL" selected='ALL'>ALL</option>
        <?php getTierOne(); ?>
</select>
```

func.php

```
<?php

function getTierOne()
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM app GROUP BY app_cn ORDER BY app_cn");
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['app_cn'].'">'.$row['app_cn'].'</option>';
        }
}

if($_GET['func'] == "drop_1" && isset($_GET['func'])) {
   drop_1($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM app WHERE app_cn='$drop_var' GROUP BY app_plan_no ORDER BY app_plan_no");

    echo '<select name="tier_two" id="tier_two" onchange="showUser()">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';

          while($drop_2 = $results->fetch_assoc())
            {
            if($drop_2['app_plan_no'] != '')
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['app_plan_no'].'">'.$drop_2['app_plan_no'].'</option>';
            }
            }
    echo '</select> ';
}
?>
```

Comment: you have to move the function call from `<body onload=showUser(str="ALL")>` to the end of the html page. when `body onload` triggers there is no combo box yet.

Comment: I already try that. Nothing happen

Comment: how is `function drop_1` called? and what is the value in `tire_two` when the page is loaded?

Comment: When the page load, it's display only the drop_1 dropdown but not the records. When I choose comp1 in drop_1 it also not displaying all comp1 records. But when I select in tier_two (for example 1) it display correctly. And when I back selecting ALL it displays all the records. I think the problem is in my Getuser.php

Comment: in `Combobox.php` you have said if there is no value for `drop_` or `tier_two` just clear the html. your ajax request happens only when you have some value is both of them. so you must have some value on both when you load the page, if you want the `showuser` function to work

Comment: I got what your trying to say. But how I can do that? I try your suggestion below but nothing change for the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
<body onload=showUser(str="ALL")>
```

you should be using

```
<body>
<!-- all your html goes here -->
</body>
<script>
    showUser();
</script>
```

When `body onload` triggers `drop_1` and `tire_two` are not created and the scrupt will just throw an exception.

**Edit:**

When first loading or if your `q=ALL`, you don't need to send the second parameter `p`. so change

```
if (str == "" || str1 == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
}
```

To

```
if (str == "" || (str != "ALL" && str1 == "")) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
}
```

**Edit 2:** Modified `Combobox.php`

```
<script> // AJAX Implementation
function showUser() {
    str = document.getElementById("drop_1").value;
    str1 = document.getElementById("tier_two").value;
    if (str == "" || (str != "ALL" && str1 == "")) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str + "&p=" + str1, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<body>

<?php include('func.php'); ?>
<select name="drop_1" id="drop_1" onchange="showUser()" style="overflow:scroll;width:100px;">
        <option value="ALL" selected='ALL'>ALL</option>
        <?php getTierOne(); ?>
</select>
<!-- your other html... -->
</body>

<script>
    showUser();
</script>
```

**Edit 3:**

This is a wild guess and may be this is what you want

changes in `func.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['func']) && $_GET['func'] == "drop_1") {
   drop_1($_GET['drop_var']); 
}else{
   drop_1(''); // when you call the func.php first time $_GET['drop_var'] is not set so call with blank drop_var
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM app WHERE app_cn='$drop_var' GROUP BY app_plan_no ORDER BY app_plan_no";
    if (empty($drop_var)){
        //if the drop_var is empty select all records
        $query = "SELECT * FROM app GROUP BY app_plan_no ORDER BY app_plan_no";
    }
    $results = $mysqli->query($query);

    echo '<select name="tier_two" id="tier_two" onchange="showUser()">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';

          while($drop_2 = $results->fetch_assoc())
            {
            if($drop_2['app_plan_no'] != '')
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['app_plan_no'].'">'.$drop_2['app_plan_no'].'</option>';
            }
            }
    echo '</select> ';
}
```

Comment: So my full script is move below of </body> ?

Comment: no. just call the script at the end. you can keep your script at the current located (better).

Comment: I'm accepting your answer but still my problem does not solved.

Comment: I have made a wild guess on what you may be thinking.

Comment: Wow it works, but why tier_two was duplicated? When I load the page the tier_two exist, and when I select comp1 in drop_1 another tier_two comes out

Comment: I think you are including `func.php` in `Getuser.php` also. If you want to do that (most probable you will) then you may need to move around code bit more.

Comment: the else{
   drop_1('');
} is the cause of duplicating the tier_two

Comment: @bansi *"instead of `<body onload=showUser(str="ALL")>`"* - There is a (another) reason for it also. I am using a similar script where I needed data shown as soon as a page loads and found the Q&A that helped me out a lot. By using `<body onload=showUser(str="ALL")>`, it made a jQuery scrolling text I am using stop *(scrolling)* and I ended up having to use `<script>showUser(str="My String"); </script>` just below the `<body>` tag. Just thought that you (and others) might like to know, *cheers*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- a link to the Q&A would be greatly helpful so that I can include it in the answer. Or you can just edit the answer for future readers.

Comment: @bansi The Q&A I mentioned is this very one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error in your javascript:

`<body onload=showUser(str="ALL")>`

Should be:

`<body onload=showUser("ALL")>`

Javascript does not support named parameters at calltime. Additionally, you should alter your onchange to be: `onchange="showUser(this)"` and change the function definition to be:

```
function showUser(elem) {
   console.log(elem.value); // now you don't have to do all the document.getElementById stuff
}
```

Comment: Actually Rob; both methods work. You may want to have a look at [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438046/nothing-display-after-i-load-the-page#comment70739866_20438133) I left under bansi's answer; it might be useful to know, *cheers*