# Body onload not execute when page load

Tags: javascript, ajax

Why my body onload not executing? When I load the page I need to display all records that selected in drop_1 dropdown is equal to ALL. I have script that sends `q` and `p` to getuser.php. The value sends are from drop_1 and tier_two dropdown.

Combobox.php

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wait_1').hide();
    $('#drop_1').change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() == "ALL") {
            $("#wait_1").hide();
            $("#result_1").hide();
        }else{
      $('#wait_1').show();
      $('#result_1').hide();
      $.get("func.php", {
        func: "drop_1",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_1').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
      }
        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response) {
  $('#wait_1').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
</script>

  <script> // AJAX Implementation
    function showUser() {
        str = document.getElementById("drop_1").value;
        str1 = document.getElementById("tier_two").value;
        if (str == "" || (str != "ALL" && str1 == "")) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str + "&p=" + str1, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    <body>

<?php include('func.php'); ?>
<select name="drop_1" id="drop_1" onchange="showUser(this.value)" style="overflow:scroll;width:100px;">
        <option value="ALL" selected='ALL'>ALL</option>
        <?php getTierOne(); ?>
</select>

    <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif" width="15px" height="15px"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span>
<div id="txtHint"></div>

    <script>
        showUser();
    </script>
```

func.php

```
<?php

function getTierOne()
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM app GROUP BY app_cn ORDER BY app_cn");
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['app_cn'].'">'.$row['app_cn'].'</option>';
        }
}

if($_GET['func'] == "drop_1" && isset($_GET['func'])) {
   drop_1($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM app WHERE app_cn='$drop_var' GROUP BY app_plan_no ORDER BY app_plan_no");

    echo '<select name="tier_two" id="tier_two" onchange="showUser()">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';

          while($drop_2 = $results->fetch_assoc())
            {
            if($drop_2['app_plan_no'] != '')
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['app_plan_no'].'">'.$drop_2['app_plan_no'].'</option>';
            }
            }
    echo '</select> ';
}
?>
```

Getuser.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
$p = $_GET['p'];
$q = $_GET['q'];
$where = '';
if ( $q != 'ALL') {
    $where = " WHERE app_cn='$q' AND app_plan_no='$p'  ";
$result1 = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM app 
    $where 
    GROUP BY counter
")or die(mysqli_error());
echo'<table>'
........
```

Comment: <body onload="showUser()" >

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nothing display after I load the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438046/nothing-display-after-i-load-the-page)

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the showUser() function is not being called after the page loads completely then call it in document.ready() call back.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
<script>
    showUser();
</script>
```

to this:

```
<script>
    function addListener(event, obj, fn) {
        if (obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener(event, fn, false);   // modern browsers
        } else {
            obj.attachEvent("on"+event, fn);          // older versions of IE
        }
    }

    addListener('load', window, showUser);
</script>
```

Also add a console.log something to your function to see if it called. Something like this:

```
function showUser() {
    console.log('Function showUser() was called!!');
```

And look in your firebug or whateveryouuse browser console.

Comment: updated my answer. Add a console.log and check if function was called.

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null @ http://localhost/app/sample/combobox.php:58 and console.log display in browser console

Comment: Cheers, so my approach is working. Now we can see a mistake some deeper in your code. You trying to get element, but there is no element with that id. open page source in your browser, find line 58 and show it to us.

Comment: str1 = document.getElementById("tier_two").value; that's is in line 58

Comment: So here is the problem in your func.php, function drop_1($drop_var) will only be called if there was a GET request.
But when the page loads you only including func.php, so there is no GET request. function drop_1 wasn't called and <select name="tier_two" id="tier_two" onchange="showUser()"> wasn't created. So there is no element for document.getElementById("tier_two")

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, but not a code generator. I can help you with a single or two answers, but I won't do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute your javascript function, you need to either add it to the `<body>` tag

```
<body onLoad="showUser();">
```

or you need to actually request it in your `<script type="text/javascript">` inside of the `<head>` tag.

```
window.onload = showUser();
```

But currently you have neither except a random call outside of your body. That may be another issue all together, but you need to keep all relevant displayed material within your `body` tag.

Comment: You need to add change your code from `str = document.getElementById("drop_1").value;` to `var str = document.getElementById("drop_1").value;` You need to properly declare your variables. Try that. And do it on all your new variables.

Comment: So define all your new variables as vars `var` should be before str, str1 and the very first instance of xmlhttp. You are also calling to an ID field `document.getElementById("txtHint")` which does not Exist anywhere in your code or page.

Comment: txthint exist, i forgot to write in here <div id="txtHint"></div>

Comment: Again, I see you made edits to your post above, but you still have not declared str and str1 as variables. It will not work at all until you do that, I promise you.